# Are there vaccines which present a risk by being re-taken too early?

Tags: vaccination, pediatrics

A friend of mine lost the vaccination information for one of his children (a 15 yo boy) and has doubts about the date for the next shot against tetanus (which in France comes together with the ones against diphtheria and <del>tuberculosis</del> polio).

Are there vaccines which **specifically** must not be taken too often, say after 5 years instead of 10 years?

<sup>*Note: I am sure that this is obvious but just in case: he is not trying to understand if the vaccine is useful (it is) or whether he should continue administrating it to himself and his kids (he will) - the exact question is about known warnings on some vaccines when they are re-taken too early (we are talking about a magnitude of years (say, now +/- 3 years), not whether to take another one after a week or so)*</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NB:** I'm going to steer clear of addressing the specific scenario and stick to the general case, your friend should of course seek advice from their primary doctor regarding the best thing to do for the child in question.

> Are there vaccines which specifically must not be taken too often, say after 5 years instead of 10 years?

**Yes**, for example [REVAXIS](https://www.drugs.com/uk/pdf/leaflet/1051255.pdf) - the 3-in-1 booster for tetanus, diphtheria and polio is not to be given within 5 years of previous shots:

> In order to minimise the risk of adverse events, REVAXIS should not be
> administered to subjects who completed a primary vaccination course or
> received a booster of a vaccine containing diphtheria or tetanus toxoids within
> the previous five years.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful - especially that REVAXIS is a common vaccine in France (my children had that exact one for instance).